# Sleep() in Win32 makes program unresponsive

Tags: c++, winapi, sleep

Basically exactly what the title says. I would like to update the text that a button contains every 1 second when the user presses that particular button. I have noted that when the program doesn't have focus it works alright and the text refreshes correctly but when I am hovering over the program or when I am trying to click on it's menu Windows inform me that the program is unresponsive and asks me if I want it terminated. When the loop finishes the program returns to its normal state. Also any action I might have done (like moving it around or closing it) while it was **Sleep()**-ing is executed after the loop. Here is a bit of code:

```
case ID_BUTTON_START:
// Code executed when pressing Start Button.
char startButtonText[30];  // Storing next loop text
 for (int i=5; i>0; i--)
    {
       sprintf(startButtonText, "Starting in ... %d", i);
       SendMessage(hwndButtonStart, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)(startButtonText));
       Sleep(1000);
     }
```

Is this normal? If not what's causing this?

Comment: Sleep after SendMessage? Did you intend PostMessage instead by any chance?

Comment: `Sleep()` is the solution to practically no problems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `WndProc` does not process messages asynchronously within an application which means all messages are expected to be handled quickly and a return value delivered immediately. You must not `Sleep` in the UI thread since it will block other UI events from being processed. Any heavy work or synchronous requests/jobs which are likely to take a long time should be performed in worker threads. There are at least three viable options:

1. Create a new ([worker thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) for the task.
2. If the task is likely to be done often, use a [thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.
3. Set and subscribe to [timer events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Your first 2 sentences cleared this out for me. Thank you very much. +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the call to `Sleep()` might be keeping you from returning from the WndProc, so your application is not processing the incomming events for 5 secs. I suggest you try to subscribe to 5 timer events in 1s, 2s,..., 5s. Like when the timer message is recieved the button text must change. I don't know a way how to do that off the top of my head.